# Как создать смарт-контракт в сети etherium написанный на solidity через python?

Tags: python, ethereum

У меня есть смарт-контракт, написанный на solidity, я хочу сгенерировать этот смарт-контракт непосредственно из Python и разместить его в сети etherium программно, автоматически, возможно ли это? Если да, то как? Есть примеры? Пример смарт-контракта у меня есть: [безопасная Удаленная покупка](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/solidity-by-example.html#safe-remote-purchase)